# String replaceAll() method replace except string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I am trying to use the `replaceAll()` method to replace a everything on a string except a a string sequence but I don't make it work, I have the following code:

Basically:

```
String message = "§eTeste"

String color = message.replaceAll(?, ""); // The problem

System.out.println(color);
```

Output should be "§e"

Code:

```
        String[] args = message.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String teste = args[i].replaceAll("§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r]", "");

            if (i == (args.length-1)) {
                if (teste.matches("http://" + "(.*)") || teste.matches("https://" + "(.*)")) {

                    String cor = "";
                    if (!args[i].matches("(.*)" + "§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r]" + "(.*)") && (sb.toString() !=null) && !sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        cor = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^(§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r])]", "");
                    }

                    if ((sb.toString() !=null) && !sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();

                        objeto.put("text", sb.toString());
                        jmessage.add(objeto);
                    }

                    JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject extra = new JSONObject();

                    extra.put("action", "open_url");
                    extra.put("value", teste);

                    objeto.put("text", cor + args[i]);
                    objeto.put("clickEvent", extra);

                    jmessage.add(objeto);
                }
                else {
                    JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();

                    sb.append(args[i]);

                    objeto.put("text", sb.toString());
                    jmessage.add(objeto);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (teste.matches("http://" + "(.*)") || teste.matches("https://" + "(.*)")) {

                    String cor = "";
                    if (args[i].matches("(.*)" + "§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r]" + "(.*)")) {
                        cor = args[i].replaceAll("[^(§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r])]", "");
                    }
                    else if (sb.toString() !=null) {
                        cor = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^(§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r])]", "");
                    }

                    if ((sb.toString() !=null) && !sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();

                        objeto.put("text", sb.toString());
                        jmessage.add(objeto);

                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(" " + cor);
                    }

                    JSONObject objeto = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject extra = new JSONObject();

                    objeto.put("text", cor + args[i]);

                    extra.put("action", "open_url");
                    extra.put("value", teste);

                    objeto.put("clickEvent", extra);

                    jmessage.add(objeto);
                }
                else {
                    sb.append(args[i] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```

jmessage is a JSONArray create out of the message that is a string input made by a sender (player/console)

The "§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r]" represents the color of the message, in this methot I am creating the JSONArray where the location of link has the click_event (every time a create a new "text" I need to send it the curret color)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can you explain and maybe give another example?

Comment: Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]"); you can try this

Comment: Why does `Test` get removed?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html check this link information about your question.;

Comment: Test is only a example i need to get the "§c" to transfer it to a nother string

Comment: here is the bigger code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution... the `replaceAll()` method can not separe more than 1 char.. because of this I have created this method to resolve the problem:

```
private String findCor(String string) {
    char[] b = string.toCharArray();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");

    for (int i = 0; i < (b.length-1); i++) {
        if ((b[i] == ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR) && ("0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfKkLlMmNnOoRr".indexOf(b[(i + 1)]) > -1)) {
            sb.append(b[i]);
            sb.append(b[(i + 1)]);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are removing `k-r` in your regexp in line 5, the letter `p` is also removed because its position in the alphabet between k and r. Due to that, you will never get a match on "http" (`teste.matches("http" ...`) further down.

Comment: It replaces the §p combination not the letter p (giving a match) Example: http://prntscr.com/jki7u8

Comment: String teste = args[i].replaceAll("§[0-9A-Fa-fK-Rk-r]", ""); The string teste is the string args[i] with out the §p not the letter p